# proper way to save NSManagedContext with latest version of Magical Record

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, magicalrecord

In order to save my current `NSManagedObjectContext` I use `[localContext MR_saveNestedContexts];` but I get a warning that the method has been deprecated.

How should I save an `NSManagedObjectContext` with the latest version of Magical Record (literally pulled from GitHub today, Jul 19 2013).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out their documentation.
https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Saving-Entities.md

Try using

```
- (void) MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:(MRSaveCompletionHandler)completion;
```

I'm not using the latest version of MagicalRecord, but I think this should be correct

```
    //get the context for the current thread
    //this context can be updated by anyone other process on this thread that uses the same MR_contextForCurrentThread call
    //it's a local store that can be merged to a parent store
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    
    //create an NSManagedObject of type YourEntity and insert it into the localContext object
    NSManagedObject *obj = [YourEntity MR_createInContext:localContext];
    
    //make any updates to obj
    
    //save the localContext async
    //this call should save all nested NSManagedObjectContexts as well (if they exist)
    [localContext  MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^{
        //when the async save is complete, this block gets executed
        //blocks work very similarly to javascript callbacks
        //basically it's a function reference or block of code that get's packaged up and can be passed around
        //In this case, the completion block allows to to run any code after the save has been completed.
    }];
```

One thing I didn't realize when I started was when I created my entity, it also inserted it into the context.  It caused me to accidentally save objects that I didn't need to persist.  To avoid this I setup a subcontext and only save it when I want to persist the objects.

```
self.context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
self.context.parentContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
```

Comment: yea not sure why you got the downvote either, it wasn't me (just upvoted to negate that). Would you mind providing one more line of code that implements the method you mentioned? I'm still earning all the syntax for Objective-C and don't really understand the withCompletion:^(BOOL Success, NSError *error)completion] that autocompletes when you type in this method...

Comment: FYI - It wasn't me that down voted, but this answer _did_ appear in the flag queue for 10k users, likely because link-only answers are not considered a Good Thing on StackOverflow. Always include enough information so that if the link breaks, your answer is still useful. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/164376) for more information.